# mvcjqgrid custom sorting function not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, mvcjqgrid

I am facing custom sorting issue with mvcjqgrid plugin.

As per my need column data should be sort in numerical order.

Column data = {M18, M2, M9, M1}, If i sort the column than column data should be shown as M1, M2, M9, M18 ....

**What I have done :** *I have added one method into plugin to add line into jquery grid "sorttype:myCustomSorting" but javascript method is not calling*.

---

```
`JavaScript function : 

function myCustomSorting(cell,obj){  
   //do something....  
}`
```

need some suggestion!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a function to `sorttype` is currently not supported on MvcJqGrid.
Only the following values are allowed:

https://github.com/robinvanderknaap/MvcJqGrid/blob/master/src/MvcJqGrid/Enums/SortType.cs#L8

You could try to use `OnSortCol` on the grid itself:

https://github.com/robinvanderknaap/MvcJqGrid/blob/master/src/MvcJqGrid/Grid.cs#L1114

You can specify a custom sort function on this property. The function is raised immediately after a sortable column is clicked and before sorting the data.

Pull-request is always welcome if you want to use sorttype ;) Shouldn't be too hard too implement.

Comment: Thanks @Robin for answer. Can we add support for custom sorting like add on method?  That i have done.Now _javascript_ method is calling after added **SetLoadOnce(true)** :). Thanks again for your quick response.

Comment: JFYI, today i am getting error while try to access "http://mvcjqgrid.skaele.it/Home/Events". Please have a look!!